# File in use when publishing asp.net site with servicestack

Tags: asp.net-core, servicestack

When publishing my Asp.net Core ServiceStack site using WebDeploy with the AppOffiline rule to IIS I sometimes get an error that the main dll file is locked by another process. After troubleshooting, it seems to be narrowed down to happening only when a client is connected to a ServerEvents stream. If I retry, I continue to get the error for a couple minutes, and then it will work.

I tried to stop the AppPool before publishing, but it takes about the same amount of time for the AppPool to shut down, which leads me to believe that the publish is failing because the AppPool is hung up, because of something with the ServerEvents.

From my research I don't see anything that would be causing this, but am kind of stuck. I am thinking of trying to use Redis Server Events to see if that eliminates the issue, but was hoping somebody might have some other advice first.

Currently, my ServerEvents configuration is pretty basic.

```
Plugins.Add(new ServerEventsFeature()
{                
   IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60),
   HeartbeatInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30)
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try with the latest ServiceStack v5.10.5 on that's now [available on MyGet](https://docs.servicestack.net/myget) which explicitly disposes each active subscription when the AppHost disposes.

Comment: I updated ServiceStack to v5.10.5, but it didn't seem to fix the issue. I still has the same error when trying to publish.

Comment: @KeithLubbers The latest v5.10.5 release is now explicitly registering an IApplicationLifetime ApplicationStopping event to make sure that AppHost.Dispose() is explicitly getting called so if you [Clear your NuGet packages cache](https://docs.servicestack.net/myget#clear-nuget-package-cache) (i.e. `nuget locals all -clear`) it will download the latest pre-release v5.10.5. Other than that I'm not sure what else could be preventing the App from shutting down.

Comment: I cleared the nuget cache and it seems to be working now. Thanks!